# Add Random Characters to a new Login - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to add two random character to the end of a newly created login name. So let's say the hard coded login name is 'TestUser'. I want to be able to add random letters and numbers to the end of 'TestUser' so it can be 'TestUser13', or 'TestUserA5'.

However I am getting an syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Below is my code where the syntax error gets returned after executing:

```
DECLARE @NewPassword    VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Sql            NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @RandomChar     NVARCHAR(50)

SET @RandomChar = N'SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 2)'
    EXEC sp_executesql @RandomChar

--Calls function to generate random password
EXEC @NewPassword = dbo.GenerateRndPassword

--Creates login with random password
SET @Sql = 'CREATE LOGIN TestUser' + @RandomChar + 'WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @NewPassword + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

--PRINT @Sql

SELECT 'TestUser' + @RandomChar AS Login
SELECT @NewPassword AS Password
```

Anyone help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues going on here. First is you have to convert your newid to a varchar so you can get the left two characters. But really don't need dynamic sql here anyway. The second issue is you need a space before WITH PASSWORD. Your final code would look something like this.

```
DECLARE @NewPassword    VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Sql            NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @RandomChar     NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT @RandomChar = LEFT(convert(varchar(50), NEWID()), 2)

--Calls function to generate random password
EXEC @NewPassword = dbo.GenerateRndPassword

--Creates login with random password
SET @Sql = 'CREATE LOGIN TestUser' + @RandomChar + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @NewPassword + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

--PRINT @Sql

SELECT 'TestUser' + @RandomChar AS Login
SELECT @NewPassword AS Password
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `NEWID()` would need to be converted or cast to a string before `LEFT()` can operate on it.

(this really ought to be a comment but I don't have enough rep.)